# How to import only functions I need from React context

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

I am new to React context and everything is going well. But after I import context inside my functional component and use `useContext` I have pass all values I passed inside provider value.

Here is my provider

```
<UserContext.Provider value={[login, checkPhoneNumber, updatePhoneNumber, getUseInfo]}>
  {props.children}
</UserContext.Provider>
```

so here I have to pass all four variables and functions.

```
  const [login, checkPhoneNumber, updatePhoneNumber, getUseInfo] = useContext(UserContext);
```

but in some cases I need to pass only function like `getUserInfo` and if I remove other functions it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing an array at Provider's value, pass an object

```
<UserContext.Provider value={{login, checkPhoneNumber, updatePhoneNumber, getUseInfo}}>
```

and then you can access as many of the passed methods you need using object destructuring

```
const {login} = useContext(UserContext);
```

or

```
const {login, checkPhoneNumber, updatePhoneNumber, getUseInfo} = useContext(UserContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `null` for any function you don't need

```
  const [null, null, null, getUseInfo] = useContext(UserContext);
```

Hope this helps.

PS you also misspelled once `getUseInfo` vs `getUserInfo`

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do something like this also (in addition to what Shmili Breuer mentions above):

```
  const [,,, getUseInfo] = useContext(UserContext);
```

base example to show how destructing works, cause this is all you're really doing:

```
var a =[1,2,3,4,5];
var [,,three,,] = a;
console.log("THREE: ", three);
```